# Libgdx game Freezes or show black screen after sometimes or on restart of devices

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

My libgdx game is running perfectly for somtimes on real devices. Samsung galaxy s# and Google nexus tab. But after opening my game again after some time my app freezes my samsung mobile and shows black screen on google nexus tablet. 
I have carefully disposed Spritebatch, stage, and all textures and sound, also Assetloader as per my knowledge.

I have also tried checking my game after restarting my device. So my game runs perfect before but after restarting it is in same freez or black screen condition.

P.S : I am just using Google analytics in my game.

Any idea what can I do more? I have read many questions regarding it here and on Google and did whatever considerable solutions are available but no luck. I have also checked this [Black Screen After Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252145/black-screen-after-restart) but no luck for me.

Comment: Do you have any static references to Textures, Shaders, SpriteBatch, or objects that reference them? That could cause this problem. `dispose` is not guaranteed to always be called (only in situations where failure to call it would truly result in a memory leak), so you can't rely on it to clean up stuff that is statically referenced.

Comment: I do have static refernces :-/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100373/android-libgdx-preferences-not-working/17101719#17101719

Comment: hmm may be this is the problem let me check it thoroughly. Thanks in Advance @P.T and also thanks a lot @ Tenfour04